# Texture for nebula or energy spheres?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, texturing, materials

Source of energy sphere:

[image]

I'm trying to build those energy balls. In shading, which texture do I use?

Also, is there anything else I have to do?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Should this be a 3D effect or just a 2D projection on the sphere?

Comment: @Blunder, 3d effect.

Answer (score 3):

Try a *Layer Weight* node and a *ColorRamp* node. For *Eevee*, the *Bloom* option can be enabled while *Cycles* requires a *Glare* node in the *Compositor*. For the reflection, choose a low *Roughness* value for the *Principled BSDF* and play with the *Specular* value.

[image: energy bubble shader]

If you add a *Hue/Sat/Value* node you can change the color with the *Hue* value (screenshot below).

For the core of the energy sphere you can add a subdivided cube ("sphere") and displace it with a *Displacement* modifier. To animate it, drive the coordinates of the texture. The shader is very similar:

[image: energy balls]

More energy materials have a look here:

- [Blender Energy FX Tutorial](https://youtu.be/9ehbb93atqo). Download is here: [Free Blender Energy FX Material](https://gum.co/GM_Energy_Material).

They use a sphere, similar shaders as shown above, and modifiers with vertex groups to create fluid like energy effects.

Comment: Thanks. good answer